# IDisposable without assigning to variable

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Usually I'd do this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("XXXX", cnn))
{
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //xxxxxx  
    }
}
```

Or even this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("XXXX", cnn))
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    //xxxxxx  
}
```

But what about this:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = new SqlCommand("XXXX", cnn).ExecuteReader())
{
    //xxxxxx  
}
```

Does that call Dispose() for the SqlCommand, even though I haven't assigned it to a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does that call IDisposable for the SqlCommand, even though I haven't assigned it to a variable?

No.  It will call `Dispose()` on the `SqlDataReader` (`dr`), since that is the object returned by the expression.

Comment: @SeanW Yes - your current code won't dispose the `SqlCommand` - so use your "or even this" option